# How to create a dynamically populated select (drop down) filter with ActiveAdmin (Formtastic)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, formtastic

I'm working on a web application based on Active Admin and am trying to understand how to create a select filter that is dynamically populated with all the unique values from a particular field.

From my understanding Active Admin uses Formtastic for these.

The scenario is countries and the code below from the resource works correctly and inserts Austria & France into the select.

But how do I this dynamically, as in, how do I go and query all the possible unique country options, and insert them into this collection?

```
filter :Country, :as => :select, :collection => ["Austria", "France"]
```

Should I do this work in the model first and then link to it in the resource?

Appreciate your help.

Thanks so much.

EDIT: Based on comments, I've now tried this, but it is erroring:

```
filter :Country2, :as => :select, :collection => proc { Country.all.collect {|country| country.name}.uniq }
```

Erorr message: uninitialized constant Country

FYI model name is Dailydeal

EDIT 2:

Here is the new working code

```
filter :Country, :as => :select, :collection => proc { Dailydeal.all.collect {|dd| dd.Country}.uniq }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have model `Country` and want to filter all its objects names, you can do something like following:

```
filter :name, as: :select, collection: -> { Country.all.collect {|country| country.name}.uniq }
```

`->` is a new syntax for lambda. This will allow you to load only currently present country names.

Another way (if you have a some static set of countries) to use constant:

in model:

`COUNTRIES = ["Australia", "USA"]` #whatsoever

and then in activeadmin:

```
filter :name, as: :select, collection: -> { Country::COUNTRIES }
```

### **EDIT**

Based on comments..

```
filter :country, as: :select, collection: -> { Dailydeal.all.collect {|dd| dd.country}.uniq }
```

### **UPDATE**

This solution (using [pluck](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck)) is said to be more efficient:

```
filter :country, as: :select, collection: proc { Product.pluck(:country).uniq.sort }
```

Comment: Hey thanks so much for your detailed answer. I've tried this and am getting an error, seeing question for edits. FYI the model is not called country, its called dailydeals .. thanks

Comment: please edit the question with exact model name, and I will update the answer :)

Comment: I assume you have :country attribute in dailydeals table, right?

Comment: yeah i do have an attribute called Country. Unfortunately it is still erroring, but it's now:

undefined method `Country2_eq' for #<Ransack::Search:0x007f6dd735f538>

Comment: why is it uppercase? and why are :Country2 and :Country different? cant be so. be back in 15 mins, try to recheck these things

Comment: yeah that was my mistake, so just renamed it to Country and it worked, thanks for your help mate! Legend!

Comment: Hey I found this to have poor performance with lots of records, have changed to:

`filter :country, :as => :select, :collection => proc { Product.pluck(:country).uniq.sort }`

It may be worth editing your answer